Double integral with dependent bounds
How can I solve this double integral:
$$\int_0^t dt'e^{-\lambda t'}\int_0^{t'} dt''e^{\lambda t''}$$
$\lambda$ is a constant.
My attempt:
$$\int_0^t dt'e^{-\lambda t'}\int_0^{t'} dt''e^{\lambda t''}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t dt'e^{-\lambda t'} \int_0^t dt''e^{\lambda t''}=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\int_0^t dt'e^{-\lambda t'}(e^{\lambda t}-1)=-\frac{1}{2\lambda^2}(e^{\lambda t}-1)(e^{-\lambda t}-1)$$
but I don't think it is correct. In particular I have problems since the double integral has dependent bounds.

Don't overthink too much : the second/inner integral can be computed straightforwardly, because $t'$ appears only in the boundary but not inside the integrand, when the first/outer integral is calculated afterwards, as it follows step by step :
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\, e^{-\lambda t'} \int_0^{t'} \mathrm{d}t''\, e^{\lambda t''}
   &= \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\, e^{-\lambda t'} \left[\frac{e^{\lambda t''}}{\lambda}\right]_{t''=0}^{t''=t'} \\
   &= \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\, e^{-\lambda t'} \frac{e^{\lambda t'}-1}{\lambda} \\
   &= \int_0^t \mathrm{d}t'\, \frac{1-e^{-\lambda t'}}{\lambda} \\
   &= \left[\frac{t'}{\lambda} + \frac{e^{-\lambda t'}}{\lambda^2}\right]_{t'=0}^{t'=t} \\
   &= \frac{t'}{\lambda} - \frac{1-e^{-\lambda t'}}{\lambda^2}
\end{align}
$$

I don't understand why the second integral can be resolved independently from the first one though, since $t'$ is in the first integral, why don't we have to take into account this?

Because an integration doesn't depend on the boundaries, as in the case of indefinite integrals, even if the primitive will be evaluated at those points at the end when dealing with a definite integral (but only after the integration itself).
